# Why does my review page appear distorted in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: support, review, internet-explorer

I use Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8. It's working fine in Google Chrome.

> [image]

When I open the review page, it appears distorted as shown in the picture above.

When I review posts,

- I can upvote or downvote it.
- I can also click on *No Action Needed*

But I am unable to click on *I'm Done* as shown in the picture shown below.

> [image]

The whole of the content appears suppressed and is not visible for review.

Comment: Maybe because its IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this exact behavior with compatibility mode, but no other way.  Please disable this as it's not needed on our sites :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You probably have compatibility mode turned on by accident. Turn it off. The rest of the SE sites seem fine in IE7 mode though.