# unable to post comments in web site

Tags: support, comments

9:48 AM EST UPDATE: Nope clearing cache did not work.

9:45: AM EST: Ok: I will try to clear and post back here. I can only EDIT the OP. No JS errors.

I am not able to post comments on my own questions or others or answers or comments made on my questions. This issue arose some time ago and I thought that stackoverflow had some issue that was eventually solved.

This has been going on for 2 days now, how can I alert a moderator or support staff?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in your console? You may want to clear your browser cache to make sure you don't have a corrupted JS copy.

Comment: You just alerted staff and moderators ;) But that's not a job for a moderator anyway, unless you somehow got a comment ban. Is there anything like a comment ban?

Comment: Testing again, lets see if this is working now.  Hey Fixed Finally!!!

Comment: In the developer tools, are you getting any errors loading any js files (netwrok tab)? What browser and os are you using?

Comment: \o/ You managed to add a comment here. :-)

Comment: @Oded: are you on a mobile connection or something? Spelling by thick thumbs™? :-P

Comment: IE10 in compatibility mode. I cleared the Java Cache using the F12 interface. Compatibility Mode was set to IE9.

Comment: That's it; switch off compatibility mode. See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) and [Why does my review page appear distorted in Internet Explorer 10?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168183)

Comment: Nope, PC in the office. I also reset all IE settings, tools, Iternet Options, Advanced tab, restore settings and reset. Restarted browser.

Comment: @htm11h: my 'mobile connection' was directed at Oded, not you. :-)

Comment: thanks gang, glad to back on the air.

Comment: @Mołot no comment ban, same way there's no vote ban - only full suspension can prevent user from commenting.